# Does react-native-video supports live streaming from hls url?

Tags: react-native, http-live-streaming, react-native-video

I'm using react-native-video for steaming hls url. It works fine with box react-native run-android but after building a bundleRelease the live streaming video is not playing

Comment: which version you use?

Comment: Yes, you can find it in the docs here. [https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video) It is the latest version I don't know abut old versions.

Comment: hey man, did you able to solve this problem ?

Answer (score -8):

simple answer is yes !
[this package will help you !](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hls-player)
first install it using

```
sudo npm -g i react-hls-player
```

in your project import the package using

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactHlsPlayer from 'react-hls-player';
```

then render it

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactHlsPlayer
    src="https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8"
    hlsConfig={{
      maxLoadingDelay: 4,
      minAutoBitrate: 0,
      lowLatencyMode: true,
    }}
  />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

dirt simple !

Comment: the question was about React-Native.